# qsort in C uses twice the amount of memory

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, quicksort, qsort

I have a program where I need to read bytes of data in RAM, sort that data using qsort, and write the data back out to a file, the catch is that I'm only allowed use a certain amount of memory to do so. 
Here's a jist of what I've done:

```
FILE *fp;
/* open file for reading up here , blah blah blah*/
...

int mb = 1024*1024;
int mem_size = 20*mb;
int total_cookies = mem_size/sizeof(Cookie);
Cookie *buffer = (Cookie *) calloc(total_cookies, sizeof(Cookie));

/* read bytes into buffer*/
 while ((result = fread(buffer, total_cookies , sizeof(Cookie), fp)) > 0) {
      qsort(buffer, total_cookies, sizeof(Cookie), compare);
      fwrite(....)
 }
 free(buffer);
```

My problem is, when I run my program against `/usr/bin/time -v` and check the maximum resident set size, I use twice the amount of memory that I'm intended to, and the problem points back to the qsort function.

How do I get qsort to sort in place, and not use extra memory?

Comment: Sadly, the C standard makes no complexity requirement on the implementation of qsort, and every standard library implementer can do pretty much whatever they want as long as the results are correct. Your only option is to write your own sorting algorithm, which you can control.

Comment: That's so nuts, because in my assignment we can't exceed a certain amount of memory, and we were told to use qsort because one of the teaching assistants said qsort, sorts in place. But when I tried explaining my results, I pretty much got the "That shouldn't be happening answer". But I don't see where I went wrong with my implementation, & I don't have any memory leaks or anything so ... I'm absolutely stumped.

Comment: Your TA was fooled by the name. [This](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.2) is what the standard has to say about `qsort`. It makes no requirement other than correctness. There's also [this source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) openly maintained by developers worldwide. Try to use those to convince you TA that they should adjust their expectations. If the TA isn't convinced, do your assignment as requested. It will either pass on the TA's library implementation, or the entire class will fail, which they won't be able to ignore.

Comment: @koikoi: qsort probably _does_ sort in place, but since it (assuming that qsort actually is implemented as quicksort) is recursive it might use a lot of stack for the recursive calls. Perhaps your data is almost sorted, or almost reverse?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy my data is pretty random. I'd almost like to call it pretty reverse.

Comment: @koikoi Even the case where the data is reversely sorted quick sort would behave poorly. If you know that `qsort` in your implementation actually uses quick sort (which it doesn't need to) you should probably shuffle the input before calling `qsort`. Quick sort works well in the "average" case which is "randomly" ordered input.

Comment: After running a test, and confirming the behavior on Ubuntu 16.04 with GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu5, it seems that it can't be the stack. I sorted a billion (random, non-sorted) doubles, 8G of data, and during sorting the RES size _doubled_. That's too much to be the stack, and it seems that (this particular) qsort actually does copy the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no requirement in the specification about the memory consumption or time complexity you will need to use another function (possibly self implemented) if you have constraints on memory consumption (at least if you want portability).

There is indeed algorithms (fx quick sort) that have `O(n log n)` complexity and `O(n log n)` memory consumption. There are probably implementations that actually use such an algorithm for implementing `qsort`, but yours is perhaps none of these.

There are other decent algorithms that require more memory. For example merge sort would require to make a copy of the data for the last merge step (which is consistent with your observation). Merge sort has it's advantages (for example having better worst case time complexity) which may be a reason why the implementation would opt for that algorithm.

Actually the implementation of `qsort` could have been a lot worse than that both time- and memorywise. The statement that `qsort` sorts in place is only true to the extent that the result finally ends up in the same array as the input, but before that it could scatter the data all over the place.